# MYSQL error al actualizar la contraseña

Tags: mysql, sql

La instalacion de mysql-server fue satisfactoria pero no puedo actualizar la contraseña del usuario **root**

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('root') where user='root';
```

pero me sale este error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('root') where user='root' at line 1

y esta la version de mysql que tengo

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un problema común que proviene desde la versión MySQL 5.7 en adelante, si no proporcionamos durante la instalación una contraseña al usuario `root`, utilizará el complemento `auth_socket` para la autenticación.

Con esto MySQL usa por defecto esta configuración y no se preocupará por tu contraseña, verificará que el usuario se esté conectando utilizando un socket UNIX para luego comparar el nombre de usuario. Si esto coincide, solo te logueará. Por eso si agregas `mysql -u root -p` accediendo con `su -` te dará acceso.

Para eso debes ver que tipo de autentificación usa tu MySQL.
Si aparece `auth_socket` debes cambiarlo a `mysql_native_password` para que puedas loguearte con la password que quieras.

Después usa este comando:

```
 UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password', authentication_string = PASSWORD('nuevaPassword') WHERE User = 'root';

 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 1):

El comando debe ser así:

```
ALTER USER 'tuUser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'otroPassword';


FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Es decir:

- Indicamos que alteraremos un valor de la tabla `user`
- Debemos identificar el nombre del usuario y el dominio en el que se encuentra por 'usuarioActual'@'localhost'
- Después de `IDENTIFIED BY` escribiremos entre comillas la nueva contraseña

**REFERENCIAS**

- [Update a password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: Muchas Gracias me ayudo bastante